# Call an Action method using Ajax in MVC4

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Action method doesn't fire in my code. Can you please show me the error. :)

here is the code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#btnSave").click(function () {

    var ContactID = $("#txtContactId").val();
    var Company = $("#txtCompany").val();
    var Status = $("#cmbStatus").val();
    var IsActive = $("#IsActive").is(':checked'); 
    var Comments = $("#txaComments").val();

    var Country = $("#cmbCountry").val();
    var Address1 = $("#txtAddress1").val();
    var Address2 = $("#txtAddress2").val();
    var City = $("#txtCity").val();
    var State = $("#txtState").val();

    var PostalCode = $("#txtPostalCode").val();
    var VatNo = $("#txtVatNo").val();
    var RegNo = $("#txtRegNo").val();
    var Phone = $("#txtPhone").val();
    var Email = $("#txtEmail").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "Customer/InsertCustomer",
        data: {
            'ContactID': ContactID,
            'Company': Company,
            'Status': Status,
            'IsActive': IsActive,
            'Comments': Comments,
            'Country': Country,
            'Address1': Address1,
            'Address2': Address2,
            'City': City,
            'State': State,
            'PostalCode': PostalCode,
            'VatNo': VatNo,
            'RegNo': RegNo,
            'Phone': Phone,
            'Email': Email
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Successfully Inserted!");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the Action method..

```
        public ActionResult InsertCustomer(string ContactID, string Company, int Status, bool IsActive, string Comments, int Country, string Address1, string Address2, string City, string State, string PostalCode, string VatNo, string RegNo, string Phone, string Email)
    {
        bool process = false;

        return Json(process, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [HttpPost] attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InsertCustomer(string ContactID, string Company, int Status, bool IsActive, string Comments, int Country, string Address1, string Address2, string City, string State, string PostalCode, string VatNo, string RegNo, string Phone, string Email)
    {
        bool process = false;

        return Json(process, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I see you get it by yourself:)

Answer (score 1):

It can be an issue with the wrong url. Use `Url.Action()` helper:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("InsertCustomer", "Customer")",
```

Also you can check your browser console for error details.

Btw, if you want to send values from the form you can use the jquery [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("InsertCustomer", "Customer")",
            data: $('form').serializeArray()
```

Comment: I've tried the way you showed. but still it's not working. 
thank you. :)

Comment: I've found the error. It's need [HttpPost] Attribute for the Action method. Thanks for your help :)
------------------------------------------
     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult InsertCustomer(string...